# Angular 6 component test with a variable into HTML

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I'm new with Angular test and I have a problem.
The first problem is with the variable `username` into a component that I use to show logged username into HTML page:
This is the test file:

```
describe('HeaderComponent', () => {
  let component: HeaderComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeaderComponent>;
  let app;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ HeaderComponent, DialogListConfigurationComponent, DialogConfirmNewConfigurationComponent ],
      providers: [ MessageService, JwtHelperService, AuthService ],  
      imports: [ DialogModule, MenubarModule, FontAwesomeModule, RouterTestingModule, TreeModule, HttpClientTestingModule, JwtModule.forRoot({
        config: {
          tokenGetter: () => {
            return sessionStorage.getItem(environment.tokenName);
          },
          //Exclude this URL from JWT (doesn't add the authentication header)
          blacklistedRoutes: [
            '/api/login',
          ]
        }
      }), ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The component is this:

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() sidebarEvent = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() clickOkButtonListConfigurationsEvent = new EventEmitter();
  username: String = this.authService.decodeToken.username;
  items = [] as MenuItem[];
  dialogListConfigurationVisible: boolean = false;
  faUserCircle = faUserCircle;
  defaultConfigurations: Configuration[];
  configurationCreated: boolean = false;
  dialogConfirmCreationVisible: boolean = false;
  constructor(private configurationService: ConfigurationService, private authService: AuthService) {   }

  ngOnInit() {
  ...
  }
```

The auth service method:

```
get decodeToken(): Jwt {
  return this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(this.getSessionToken);
}
```

The `should create` test fails with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of null`

Answer (score 3):

You need to **Mock your AuthService** since this is a component test.

you can do that by providing an object in the module initialization code

```ts
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ HeaderComponent, DialogListConfigurationComponent, DialogConfirmNewConfigurationComponent ],
  providers: [
    MessageService,
    JwtHelperService,
    {provide: AuthService, useClass: AuthServiceMock} ],  
  imports: [ DialogModule, MenubarModule, FontAwesomeModule, RouterTestingModule, TreeModule, HttpClientTestingModule, JwtModule.forRoot({
    config: {
      tokenGetter: () => {
        return sessionStorage.getItem(environment.tokenName);
      },
      //Exclude this URL from JWT (doesn't add the authentication header)
      blacklistedRoutes: [
        '/api/login',
      ]
    }
  }), ]
})
.compileComponents();
```

the `AuthServiceMock` class should implement the same interface as the original one. it can be something like this:

```ts
export class AuthServiceMock {
  // ...
  decodeToken: {
    username: 'testUser'
  };
}
```

than, before creating the component, setup the mock class if you don't want to set a default inside the mock.

**NOTE:** you can do this last step without creating a mock, but that will break the separation of concerns in your tests.

```ts
beforeEach(() => {
    let authServiceMock: AuthServiceMock = TestBed.get(AuthService);
    authServiceMock.decodeToken = { username: 'anotheruser' };

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

This should allow for the `HeaderComponent` run the `this.authService.decodedToken.username` line.

As a guideline: need to mock dependencies that rely on outside data.

You might also be able to remove dependencies of the original `AuthService` if previously you included them in the test module initialization. for example, if `JwtHelperService` is only used internally for `AuthService`, the test module can exclude that provider.

Comment: It works, from your answer I fixed the bug without the mock

Comment: @luca it can work without the mock, but it means you test the AuthService in these tests as well. Usually, in unit tests you want to test each "part" by itself

Answer (score 0):

From the @Thatkookooguy answer I got the problem and I add this two raw inside the beforeEach avoid so the use of mock object

```
const authService: AuthService = TestBed.get(AuthService);
authService.saveToken("token string");
```